# Broken Gem Path on Terminal Start Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

When opening a new terminal I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
        2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
        1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in `to_spec'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 7 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/tkellogg/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

Bash Profile looks like:

```sh
. ~/.bashrc

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

bashrc looks like;

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

I've set the default system ruby to be 2.6.5 and I've upgraded homebrew.

Any ideas?

Running `bundle update --bundler` gives `env: ruby: Argument list too long`

This is the result of `gem env`:

```
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- gem-wrappers (LoadError)
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.7 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 456) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/me/.gem
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
     - /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Users/me/anaconda3/bin
     - /Users/me/.node/bin
     - /Users/me/.yarn/bin
     - /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin
     - /Users/me/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/gos/go1.8.3/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/overlay/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/bin
     - /Users/me/go
     - /Users/me/go/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
     - ~/npm-global/bin
     - /Users/me/.yarn/bin
     - /Users/me/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/gos/go1.8.3/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/overlay/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/bin
     - /Users/me/go
     - /Users/me/go/bin
     - /Users/me/.yarn/bin
     - /Users/me/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.yarn/bin
     - /Users/me/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/gos/go1.8.3/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/overlay/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/bin
     - ~/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/go/bin
     - /Users/me/anaconda3/bin
     - /Users/me/.node/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/gos/go1.8.3/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.3/global/overlay/bin
     - /Users/me/.gvm/bin
     - /Users/me/go
     - /Users/me/go/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
     - ~/npm-global/bin
     - /Users/me/.yarn/bin
     - /Users/me/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /usr/local/mysql/bin
     - /usr/local/mysql/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Please update your question to include output of `gem env` .  Sounds like you have problems with your `PATH` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have installed ruby with Homebrew but you're trying to use RVM which may be causing problems.  If this is the case you probably should start over.

First uninstall RVM

```
rvm implode
```

Then uninstall ruby

```
brew uninstall ruby
```

Then reinstall RVM see https://rvm.io/rvm/install

UPDATE based on your `gem env` your `PATH` variable is clearly messed up.  You could try to fix it by looking at answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113419/how-can-i-reset-path-to-its-default-value-in-ubuntu) also you can [try this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from). But it might be easier to just set up a new user account and start with a fresh shell setup, and rerun the above steps.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get a different error though on terminal start: `bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
env: ruby: Argument list too long`

Comment: Ok I'll check the link out.

Comment: see updated, added 2nd link to one more option to try